# P440 defect, can I replace P440ar

Tags: raid, hp

Quick question:

I have a HP DL160 Gen 9 server with P440 raidcontroller. ILO reports this one is defective. Disks are OK; after rebooting, the server works for about an hour. I have a P440AR in stock; can I replace this card without losing the data and configuration?

Comment: Could you generate an AHS log from ILO? Let me check if this could be helpul to clarify the failure, if the controller have damage, you need to call to HP customer support for check the warranty and the replacement. when you replace this kind of smart controllers the RAID configuration stills there after the replacement you can check the controller & HDD health in the SSA ( Smart Storage Administrator) im an HP employee

Answer (score 3):

Post the error message here. It's rare to see something like that on a Smart Array controller, but without the error message, it's even harder to diagnose.

***Call HP for warranty service.***

This is a new server (*Gen9*). You have factory warranty for three years from purchase. This is better solved through that channel rather than here on Server Fault, because you've already acknowledged that you have a hardware fault.

As for your other controller, they are of the same model and generation... so yes, they're compatible. But it makes sense to understand the full scope of the issue (system board, cache, backplane) before making a recommendation to swap a new controller in.

Answer (score 1):

p440 = pci-e slot

p440ar = non-pci-e slot but directly plugged onto the motherboard elsewhere

Comment: You're mostly right, the 'ar' is PCIe in terms of pin-outs, signals and capabilities - it's just not packaged in the same way as a regular PCIe adapter.

Comment: i have no idea what 'mostly right' should mean when the only difference is the connector.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't having a go at you - I just mean the 'non-pci-e' bit, as it is PCIe spec in every way but physically - you were right, I was just adding a bit of detail

Answer (score 0):

calling hp  for warranty service are implicated to generate some logs one of them are the ADU report on the SSA ( smart storage administrator) or.. this is how i did to check controllers related failures on this servers, try to download one of them and maybe the perspective change, note: this have no related with a formware update ok? if the support agent comments about this pls take an advantage and request to check the logs or make some tests with the insigth diagnostics tool over intelligent provisioning.

have a great weekend

Answer (score 0):

i am googling for info between the 2, and i bump across this post. here are my findings...

from - http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04346299.pdf?ver=1.0
and http://www.hp.com/hpinfo/newsroom/press_kits/2014/ComputeEra/HP_SmartStorage_ProLiantGen9_DataSheet.pdf

HP Smart Array P440 Controller comes in a PCIe 3.0 low-profile, half-height form factor, and the 
P440ar comes in a Flexible Smart Array form factor SAS RAID controller with internal ports.

Key features
• Internal port (P440): 1 x 8 Mini-SAS double-wide (eight total SAS 12 Gb/s capable physical links)
• Internal port (P440ar): 2 x 4 Mini-SAS (eight total SAS 12 Gb/s capable physical links)
• Slot type (P440): x8 PCIe 3.0
• Slot type (P440ar): Flexible Smart Array and Smart Host Bus Adapter slot

For Caching: 
FBWC (P440): 4 GB FBWC (up to 14.9 GB/s maximum cache bandwidth)
FBWC (P440ar): 2 GB FBWC (up to 14.9 GB/s maximum cache bandwidth)

They look essentially the same thing, just that the AR is known to be an upgraded model (more efficient, less power, use less memory, etc etc etc)

Having said that, considering that the SLOTS are different!!! no you can't simply swap them around just like that...

even if you have the slots in the system, since the boot procedures are different, you might need to do some tweaking etc on the BIOS, so instead of going through all these unknowns and pains, it'll be much better to simply call HP Enterprise support and get them to change.

But if you're adventurous enough, while they're there, no harm trying it out yea???